# for paypal chained payments getting error "Your payment can't be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using Angelleye library for implementing the paypal chain payment.
I have paypal paynow button on my site on click of it would get redirected to sandbox.When login with the payer credentials[sandbox] and proceed to pay its giving error as

> Your payment can't be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again.

When I do the parallel payment with the same payer credentials its working fine.
I tried the steps mentioned in below artice, and these settings were already present.
https://support.zoho.com/portal/ticketpro/ShowEntityInfo.do?module=Solutions&id=e45884bf9b98e5a47533e4c420d15e8b0b498ee34174141d&showpage=DetailsView&loadType=rightleft&isload=true&prevModule=Home

So my question why is this error coming only for chained payment.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the request?

Comment: here is the request- https://codeshare.io/IMKV0

Comment: Try getting rid of the funding constraints and see if that helps.

Comment: I have removed $FundingTypes = array('ECHECK', 'BALANCE', 'CREDITCARD') and send the request .. but did not work .. here is the request https://codeshare.io/pKWMf .. is this what you asked me to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your request has this in it:

```
<deviceId xmlns="">DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE</deviceId>
```

That is the default value that is supposed to be replaced with some value of your own.

Also, get rid of any other array sets in the request that aren't being used.  Looks like you're including some sender parameters that don't need to be there...

```
  <sender>
    <useCredentials xmlns=""></useCredentials>
  </sender>
```

Comment: I have replaced DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE with " "  , and the request xml looks like https://codeshare.io/6U3yl ... but still getting the same error.. I have also tried to replace DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE with some random value.. but didn't work

Comment: This is just the SetPaymentOptions request.  What about the Pay request?  Are you getting a successful Pay response?  Is this SetPaymentOptions response successful even though it's not working when you get to PayPal?

Comment: Sorry, the error was for Pay request first and same error came when I proceeded for SetPaymentOptions.. please ignore that SetPaymentOptions request I sent.. this is the Pay request https://codeshare.io/Nns7g .. for which i am getting error

Comment: After trying many things I got rid of that error message.Earlier 2 sandbox receivers I used in chain payment were registered with country Australia. I have deleted those receivers and prepared 2 new accounts and registered them with US.I made Payer to pay these new US receivers which worked successfully and receivers received amount.But I don't know why its not working for AUS receivers which I need ultimately.